# enable to marquee text from left to right continously

Tags: ios

i want to make continuously marquee a text from left to right direction. I have using following code to use if any one have answer please tell me thnx in advanced.....

```
NSString *theMessage = @"Hello, my name is Enigo Montoya. You killed my father, prepare to die";
messageSize = [theMessage sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
messageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, messageSize.width, 19)]; //x,y,width,height
[messageView setClipsToBounds:YES]; // With This you prevent the animation to be drawn outside the bounds.
[self.view addSubview:messageView];
lblTime = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, messageSize.width, 19)]; //x,y,width,height
[lblTime setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
lblTime.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
[lblTime setText:theMessage];
[lblTime setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
lblTime.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, messageSize.width, 19); //x,y,width,height
[messageView addSubview:lblTime];
float duration = messageSize.width / 30; // This determines the speed of the moving text.
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:messageView cache:YES];
lblTime.frame = CGRectMake(-messageSize.width, 0, messageSize.width, 19); //x,y,width,height
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: it will marquee perfectly only one time it will not marquee the text at a continuously so please tell me

Comment: I'd guess that `UIViewAnimationTransitionNone` isn't enough. If I remember well, there is a repeat option and a reverse one too?

Comment: guys i will try and it will work perfectly so lets check the below code

Answer (score 0):

k i have done with this code just check it out guys

```
- (void)marqueeMessage:(id)sender
{
 // For Marquee text From left To right with Continously
    NSString *theMessage = @"WelCome To Wishing Well";
    messageSize = [theMessage sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]];

    messageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, messageSize.width, 19)]; //x,y,width,height
    [messageView setClipsToBounds:YES]; // With This you prevent the animation to be drawn outside the bounds.


    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(0, 20, messageSize.width, messageSize.height))];


    [label setText:theMessage];

    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    float duration = messageSize.width / 60; // This determines the speed of the moving text.

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

  //  [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:messageView cache:YES];
   // [UIView beginAnimations:@"test" context:nil];

   // [UIView setAnimationDuration:10];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(marqueeMessage:)];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    label.frame = CGRectMake(360,20,messageSize.width,messageSize.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

then you have to put the below code it's work for left to right marquee text continuously

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self marqueeMessage:messageView];
}
```

i hope its work for all the guys @alfa...